# Java- Comparing names to a list of names using if/else and switch statements

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I am a beginner coder who is trying to figure out how to use nested if/else and switch statements. I decided to challenge myself to write 2 programs (one with if/else and one with switch) that will compare 1 person's name to at least 15 other people's. If that 1 name matches with any of the 15 other names (besides that person's own name), it will print something. For example, the 15 names will be the names of everyone on a football team. I want to see if someone on the team has someone that shares their name. For the if/else program, I currently have this:

```
package practice;

    public class ClassmatesIfElse {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String name = "person";
            if(name.equals("person1")|| name.equals("person2") || name.equals("person3") || name.equals("person4") || name.equals("person5") || name.equals("person6") || name.equals("person7") || name.equals("person8") || name.equals("person10"))
                System.out.println("Duplicate");
            else System.out.println("Unique");
        }

    }
```

But obviously, it is very cumbersome and it doesn't work unless you remove the person you want to test from the list, which kind of defeats the purpose of the program. And I do not know where to start for the switch statement one. What is the best way to go about this? Thank you.

Comment: `if..else` is not the best solution for this. Use a `List` or a `Set` for this

Comment: So, your question is: how to check if a given string is present more than once in a list, right? The first sep is to actually have a List<String> (or an array of Strings: String[]). Then you wouldn't use if/else nor switch, but a loop, to count how many times a given value is present in the list. Learn about arrays and collections, and about loops.

Comment: you can use loop to make it less cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I agree with the comments that if you are looking for the most efficient way to determine if there are duplicates in 15 names, that you would want to use something other than nested if/then statements or a switch. I would actually suggest using a Map for this kind of work, storing the name as the key, and the count of its appearance as the value (I'm happy to create an example of this; just let me know).

However to answer your question of how you would execute the same code using a switch statement, please see below. The code actually ends up being quite lengthy but it perhaps easier to read:

```
class SwitchExample {

    private static final String SUCCESS= "Hey! You have a name doppleganger in the class!";

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String name = "person";

        switch(name) {
        case "person1":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person2":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person3":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person4":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person5":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person6":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person7":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person8":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        case "person10":
            System.out.println(SUCCESS);
            break;

        default:
             System.out.println("Your name is unique in this class!");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just thinking of random ways to use switch statements just to get used to them, so I did not think of using anything else besides if/else or switch statements. Thank you.